# Apache httpd.conf mod_rewrite canceled if .htaccess uses mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

Darn it took a while tracking this quirk down. I have global rewrite-rules defined in `httpd.conf` (or in an include; won't make a difference), to force an external redirect for certain URL patterns:

```
<Directory "/home/*">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^.*wrong\.php$ http://example.net/void.html [R,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

This works brilliant for any virtual host that doesn't have a `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite. However, if a vhost uses any mod_rewrite rules at all, the above is not working. Even a mere `RewriteEngine on`, without any rules specified, is enough to cancel out the `httpd.conf` rules for the vhost. Is this expected behavior? On Apache/2.2.15. I've tried with and without R & L flags, with and without a `<Directory>` wrapping, and declared before or after virtual hosts, but the rules simply won't work.

Someone save my sanity and tell me how to have (non-conflicting) rules in `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` working together. It must be possible, and I'd expect it to be the default behavior?

**Edit:** As requested, a sample `.htaccess` file: =^_^=

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Even just that and that only. Enough to make the rules not match, seems like any earlier `mod_rewrite` gets wiped out and a new clean rule set started when `.htaccess` kicks in. Also, any other line having to do with `mod_rewrite` causes the same. If I stick into the `.htaccess` e.g. `RewriteRule ^([X-Z])heRmaGerd[1-3]\.FOObAR$ /wherever/$1` (with the `RewriteEngine on`, or by itself as the only line), it will surely not match, but is enough cancel out all that was defined before.

Comment: Are you certain it's being cancelled? Or is it that you have a rule that's matching the new request? The latter seems more likely but, without your `.htaccess`, there's not much I can help you with.

Comment: Well it certainly isn't happening, so I presume it's canceled. There are no later matching rules in the `.htaccess`. Like I said, even a mere "RewriteEngine on", as the only thing in the `.htaccess` file, is enough to make it not happen. If I comment it out, the `httpd.conf` rule matches as expected. Same pattern tested across several domains. Also, there's no other mod_rewrite use anywhere in the `*.conf` files, so it's a mystery to me what triggers this behavior.

Comment: I can confirm that you are not crazy :), it really behaves so, even on 2.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like (at least on 2.4.6) that `RewriteOptions  inherit` helps, placed either in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`.

According to [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions), this should only force VirtualHost to inherit rules from main server configuration, or in per-directory context to inherit parent directory's `.htaccess` configuration, but I tested and it seems to resolve your issue.

Also:

> Rules inherited from the parent scope are applied after rules
>   specified in the child scope.

Comment: Brilliant, this solves it. However, I see that the declaring `RewriteOptions inherit` must go into the child `.htaccess`, declaring it in parent context (in `httpd.conf` anyway) has no effect. Seems to be the only way on 2.2.x (which is all I can get on CentOS). Oh well, that much code replication I can deal with! So long, evil seekers of `wp-login.php` and `xmlrpc.php` and whatnot! All the httpd error log litter was driving me mad, hard to spot any actual errors from that bulk of junk.